# Button will not change Activities using Eclipse

Tags: android, android-activity

I have been working on an android app for a while now, and just recently I have hit a wall in the code. For some reason, when I hit a button in the app that should change the activity, it keeps saying "the application has stopped unexpectedly" and exits out. I have done a lot of research on the subject of how to do it and tried many variations on the code to try and get it to work and still i get the error. here is what I have been using:

```
    semester = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSemester);
    semester.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
         Intent isemester = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(isemester);
           }
        });
```

So are there any problems with this code? and also, is there some code that must be placed in the second activity java file (in this case MainActivity) to get it to change?

Edit:
I looked at the LogCat like Oren said and saw that it was saying

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ com.william.android.test/com.william.android.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException"

This is what I have in my Test Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="Semester Grade" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.william.android.test.MainActivity" />
            <catagory android:name="android.intent.catagory.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

here is what I have under OnCreate() :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gradehave = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGradeHave);
    gradewant = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGradeWant);
    finalworth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFinalWorth);

    needed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNeeded);
    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCalc);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gw = Double.parseDouble(gradewant.getText().toString());
            gh = Double.parseDouble(gradehave.getText().toString());
            pf = Double.parseDouble(finalworth.getText().toString());
            pf = (pf/100);
            pg = (1 - pf);
            n = (gw - (pg * gh)) / pf;
            needed.setText(" " + n);

        }

    });
home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome_Screen.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post the relevant logcat output ?

Comment: @Oren okay i have no idea what the stuff in logcat means, but there are 20 messages popping up in the logcat, 18 of which are marked E one is D and one is W. Is there something specific that i could look for in these messages that would help find the errors? Or would it be easier if i posted all of them? Thanks a ton for the help

Comment: you should look for error descriptions (usually lines that don't start with "at"). see what kind of error you have (my guess would be along the lines of "no activity found", but that's just a guess). if you still have trouble you can edit your question and add the whole logcat output.

Comment: Okay so I added the logcat info that sounds like what contains the problem, and then also the info from my Test Manifest, hopefully this information shows the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: it would seem that something is null when it shouldn't be, in your MainActivity (most likely somewhere in it's `onCreate()`). once again, posting the relevant code will speed up the answering process :)

Comment: Alright, i posted all of the code under my onCreate() for MainActivity.java, but I'm just not sure what to look for to fix something that is null. I had the MainActivity.java as the base of my program, and everything worked fine before I added any of the other screens, but then I decided to try and add a welcome screen and that's when I started having errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your oncreate method, you didn't define 'home'. If its a button, you should first findviewbyid it before setting click listener.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I just would like to ask you what you mean by "define 'home'". I'm really new at this so I haven't learned a lot of things yet. Also, I have a findViewById for my buttons under the onCreate() at least I thought. Did I maybe put it in the wrong place? Thanks again

Comment: In your code(onCreate method) you have set an onclick listener (home.setOnClickListener). Before setting the click listener you have to initialize the button just like you did with calc button (by findViewById)

Comment: Sorry that it took so long for me to respond. But thank you so much, that fixed it! Everything appears to be working properly now, and hopefully it will stay that way. Thanks again, that was very helpful of you and everyone who helped me out with this!